# How to make webpage that remembers the choices made via javascript change attributes?

Tags: javascript

**Hello** , This is the code that can change the image src and I am using it offline .It has 2 button , one of which turns on the light and other turns off it. It works well! **But problem is it doesn't remember the choice** i made once i reload the page. Ex. If i turn on the light , it shows the glowing bulb but forgets after reload.
Note: I have tried some online solutions but since it was about something related to javascript, it didn't seem to work.
***Target is chrome only!***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>
<p>JavaScript can change HTML attributes.</p>
<p>In this case JavaScript changes the src (source) attribute of an image.
</p>
<button 
onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on 
the light</button>
<img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">
<button 
onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off 
the light</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `localStorage` to save data.

Comment: I just request you to tell me how.. (I am a beginner) I searched but could find a way.

Comment: there are a few client side storage options https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/offline/storage/

Comment: Or use cookie to save and gather data.

Comment: @TusharThakare Google "javascript localstorage tutorial"

Comment: I am using a total offline project. Cant use online stuff.

Comment: `localStorage` is not online it is local. It is there for you until you remove your cookies etc. Hold on I will show you

Comment: Okay there folks. I tried localstorage,cookie,cache from the googled results .. but I think that isn't working since this one has to something about changing  src of image. Thats what my question is about . How can get it working in this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already noted you can use localStorage to store the src and load it next page load. To use this for your example you could use the following code:-

**Html**

```
<button id="btn1">Turn on the light</button>
<img id="myImage" src="off.png">
<button id="btn2">Turn off the light</button>
```

**JS**

```
//set src on page load
if(localStorage.imgSrc) {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = localStorage.imgSrc;
}

//set src and localStorage on click
document.getElementById('btn1').onclick = function() { 
    localStorage.imgSrc = document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'on.png'; 
}
document.getElementById('btn2').onclick = function() { 
    localStorage.imgSrc = document.getElementById('myImage').src = 'off.png'; 
}
```

Comment: Its working !
(I tried to try this kind of code , but maybe for some reasons it didn't work)
I know this was kindaa noob question. But you took it seriously. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use either localstorage that is being supported by the most modern browsers or use cookie.

What i would do is to check in a function if localstorage is being supported if not use cookie like this

```
function localStorageExists(){
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(simpleTest, simpleTest);
        localStorage.removeItem(simpleTest);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}

function saveOption(value) {
    if(localStorageExists() === true){
        // available use local storage
        localStorage.setItem(option, value);
    }else{
        // unavailable use cookie
        createCookie("option", value, 30);
    }
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}
```

you can also have a function that detects and reads accordingly ;)